# Translate screen drawing to another part of the screen

Tags: c++, windows, graphics

Is it possible to make it so that all drawing to an area "A" is translated to an area "B"?

For example drawing to the area(0,0)(100,100) and have it appear in area(200,200)(300,300).

Comment: 'Yes". At the very least it depends on the specific drawing mechanism. Some methods have built-in translation support. Others will allow multiple "windows" to be opened (and thus placed relatively prior to any drawing). Or one might even apply such transformations higher..

Comment: Your question could use some clarification. Do you want simple translation, that is you specify one coordinate but the drawing appears somewhere else or do you mean an echo where it appears at both locations? The first is generally quite easy the second would be a bit more involved.

Comment: perhaps i wasn't clear enough. i want it to make one segment of the screen drawn by **any** application to be drawn elsewhere on the screen. i want to make a sliding puzzle using the actual screen.

Comment: http://malware.wikia.com/wiki/DesktopPuzzle
this does something similar. but i want it to be live.

Comment: I _assume_ it works the following way: 1. open a window fullscreen (i.e. without decoration) but do not fill it. 2. make a snapshot and store as image internally 3. output image in the window (the user cannot notice the difference). The rest is a loop which modifies the image (with or without user input) and re-displays it. I came to this idea as I just played with [`QWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html) a bit these days. I guess, this would be a nice programming-puzzle in Qt (essentially using `QWindow` and `QPixmap`) (if I only had enough time and less hobbies...)

Answer (score 2):

The question is actually tagged with [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) and [graphics](/questions/tagged/graphics). This might have been targeted to Win32 and GDI (where I've unfortunately nearly no experience). So, the following might be seen as proof of concept:

I couldn't resist to implement the idea / concept using [`QWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html) and [`QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html).

The concept is:

1. open a window fullscreen (i.e. without decoration)
2. make a snapshot and store it internally (in my case a )
3. display the internal image in window (the user cannot notice the difference)
4. perform a loop where pixmap is modified and re-displayed periodically (depending or not depending on user input).

And this is how I did it in Qt:

1. I opened a [`QWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html) and made it fullscreen. (Maximum size may make the window full screen as well but it still will have decoration (titlebar with system menu etc.) which is unintended.)
2. Before painting anything, a snapshot of this window is done. That's really easy in Qt using [`QScreen::grabWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow). The grabbed contents is returned as [`QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) and stored as member of my derived `Window` class.
3. The visual output just paints the stored member [`QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html).
4. I used a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to force periodical changes of the [`QPixmap`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html). To keep the sample code as short as possible, I didn't make the effort of shuffling tiles. Instead, I simply scrolled the pixmap copying a small part, moving the rest upwards, and inserting the small stripe at bottom again.

The sample code `qWindowRoll.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Window: public QWindow {
  private:
    // the Qt backing store for window
    QBackingStore _qBackStore;
    // background pixmap
    QPixmap _qPixmap;

  public:
    // constructor.
  Window():
    QWindow(),
    _qBackStore(this)
    {
      showFullScreen();
    }
    // destructor.
    virtual ~Window() = default;
    // disabled:
    Window(const Window&) = delete;
    Window& operator=(const Window&) = delete;

    // do something with pixmap
    void changePixmap()
    {
      enum { n = 4 };
      if (_qPixmap.height() < n) return; // not yet initialized
      const QPixmap qPixmapTmp = _qPixmap.copy(0, 0, _qPixmap.width(), n);
      //_qPixmap.scroll(0, -n, 0, n, _qPixmap.width(), _qPixmap.height() - n);
      { QPainter qPainter(&_qPixmap);
        qPainter.drawPixmap(
          QRect(0, 0, _qPixmap.width(), _qPixmap.height() - n),
          _qPixmap,
          QRect(0, n, _qPixmap.width(), _qPixmap.height() - n));
        qPainter.drawPixmap(0, _qPixmap.height() - n, qPixmapTmp);
      }
      requestUpdate();
    }

  protected: // overloaded events

    virtual bool event(QEvent *pQEvent) override
    {
      if (pQEvent->type() == QEvent::UpdateRequest) {
        paint();
        return true;
      }
      return QWindow::event(pQEvent);
    }

    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *pQEvent)
    {
      _qBackStore.resize(pQEvent->size());
      paint();
    }

    virtual void exposeEvent(QExposeEvent*) override
    {
      paint();
    }

    // shoot screen
    // inspired by http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-screenshot-cpp.html
    void makeScreenShot()
    {
      if (QScreen *pQScr = screen()) {
        _qPixmap = pQScr->grabWindow(winId());
      }
    }

  private: // internal stuff
    // paint
    void paint()
    {
      if (!isExposed()) return;
      QRect qRect(0, 0, width(), height());
      if (_qPixmap.width() != width() || _qPixmap.height() != height()) {
        makeScreenShot();
      }
      _qBackStore.beginPaint(qRect);
      QPaintDevice *pQPaintDevice = _qBackStore.paintDevice();
      QPainter qPainter(pQPaintDevice);
      qPainter.drawPixmap(0, 0, _qPixmap);
      _qBackStore.endPaint();
      _qBackStore.flush(qRect);
    }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  Window win;
  win.setVisible(true);
  // setup timer
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(50); // 50 ms -> 20 Hz (round about)
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    &win, &Window::changePixmap);
  qTimer.start();
  // run application
  return app.exec();
}
```

I compiled and tested with Qt 5.9.2 on Windows 10. And this is how it looks:

[image: Snapshot sequence of qWindowRoll]

*Note:* On my desktop, the scrolling is smooth. I manually made 4 snapshots and composed a GIF in GIMP – hence the image appears a bit stuttering.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it’s a place to start at least. I would want to avoid using a window. Anyway thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I'm not sure whether direct desktop manipulation is possible at all. I believe, these fun tools (as well as screen-savers) always use such trick with an "invisble" window. I forgot to mention that, additionally, the window can be marked to be "always on top". The shuffling of tiles could be achieved in a similar way - I just left this out as it had needed much more code than the simple scrolling.

Comment: I can draw directly to the screen (main context). But this easily gets drawn over again. If I could redirect drawing it would solve that issue. “Always on top” could solve the issue too.